# phpmyadmin don't have 'users' tab

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just finished installing phpmyadmin. However, it seems like the 'users' or 'priviledges' tab in the main navigation panel is missing. So I can't add new users to my database. Any idea where to start looking?

Answer (score 25):

The answer is to go to `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` instead of `localhost/phpmyadmin`. It works!

Comment: Doesn't work for all servers; probably only when installing phpMyAdmin locally (which isn't specified in the question).

Comment: In [other situations](https://serverfault.com/q/295285) with MySQL `localhost` fails but `127.0.0.1` works. Damn annoying.

Comment: what about who is acessing thru a remote server ?

Comment: @DiegoFavero This is what worked for me: Clear cookies, log out and log back in.

Answer (score 14):

It's in the `Privileges` tab

That's where you can add new users

[image]

Comment: there's no privilege tab either

Comment: you need to be on the *home screen* where you have the list of all your databases, not when you click on a table

Comment: I have the same problem as the person that asked the question. There is no users or priveleges tab in the homescreen..

Comment: are you connected with root user? maybe the user you are connected with does not have enough privileges to view the privileges.

Answer (score 13):

There's this bug in phpmyadmin (or feature? who knows anymore) that occurs if you've been logged in as a user without permissions. The solution is to clear your browser's cookies. For best results, restart the mySQL server while you're at it.

I'm using the XAMPP package with Apache and mySQL on Windows 7, and this worked for me.

Comment: @NickySmits and the other did? How did not work? There was an error? How about asking another question and telling us what you tried?

Comment: This worked for me, im using XAMPP. problem was occurred when trying to revoke a specific database privileges

Comment: @MahdiJavaheri imagine my surprise to log in to SO and see that my 6.5 year old answer (to a 7 year old question) helped somebody. I'm happy to be of service. Best wishes!

Comment: @John I'm more surprised why this bug still exist in latest version of XAMPP :D

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. If you have CPanel, you can create a user (same place as creating a DB), and then add the user to the Database through the Cpanel.

Comment: Yes! At the very bottom of the page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in Privileges Tab click on Add a new User

Answer (score 1):

It apparently only comes when you are `localhost`. So make sure you are accessing it via that host name and not some other virtual named server. I had the same problem because I was accessing it using `local` which I set up as an alias to `localhost`.

Comment: No, I have it in one site, but not in another site, both not local

Answer (score 1):

i just want to share what I found out

Initially, i have users tab in phpmyadmin, now I can only access it thru `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin`

- Here's the first thing I think caused me to lose "users" tab

but then i suddenly have my host file modified (in windows  "Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts")

it says

```
127.0.0.1 somehostname
#127.0.0.1       localhost
```

- Another thing but I doubt if its related

then I changed apache config httpd.conf to open my wamp on the network not just localhost

```
<Directory "D:/Program Files (x86)/wamp/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    # Online --> Require all granted

    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove

    Require local
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

- I reverted hosts file and accessed phpmyadmin using localhost which is = 127.0.0.1 and voila!

Comment: How odd! on the older versions I used using 'localhost/xampp' then navigating to phpMyAdmin let me use the privileges but the version I am running now '5.5.27' hides it! I then tried '127.0.0.1/xampp' and it appeared! :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into problem with an earlier set up account like "phpmyadmin", until i use another login: root / "rootpassword"  (which is also root password)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I was using the username I was prompted to create on installation. I'm using Crunchbang, a Debian distro so I installed through command line using apt-get. When I was logged in, the User: field was showing as username@localhost. I logged out and logged back in but this time I put root as the username and used the same password as my user account and I was given access.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem not on localhost but on a bluehost account. For some reason phpMyAdmin doesn't has root access so do not have the privilege tab. You can add user by using MySQL Databases instead of phpMyAdmin

Comment: This is OK until you want to do something interesting like slave replication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WHM/cPanel, this tab was recently removed.

See: https://features.cpanel.net/topic/as-an-administrator-i-want-to-manage-table-level-privileges-in-mysql-so-i-dont-need-to-leave-cpanel-whm-for-this-administrative-duty

Comment: Posting links to external sites is not as helpful as quoting relevant snippets/paragraphs/etc so that the answer is self-contained here.  If this website or page goes away, this answer won't be helpful anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Do this steps and try to login as root and new password ..

```
To change the mysql password for the root user, do the following:
```

> 1. unload mysqld.nlm
> 2. at the console, type: mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --autoclose
> 3. at the server console type mysql

This will bring you to the mysql prompt.  At this prompt type the following: (Where ******** is the new password, NOTE: the single quotes ARE REQUIRED)

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('********') WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Flush privileges will make the change take effect immediately.

You can, in MySQL Version 3.22 and above, use the SET PASSWORD statement: (Where ******** is the new password, NOTE: the single quotes ARE REQUIRED)

```
shell> mysql -u root mysql
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR root=PASSWORD('********');
```

Another way to set the password is by using the mysqladmin command: (Where ******** is the new password)

```
shell> mysqladmin -u root password ********
shell> mysqladmin flush-privileges
```